# Dockerfile specifying path of API

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker for the first time. I have a web application in angular and a backend application in python/flask. After some struggle, I finally managed to get everything to work, but docker can't find my API program in my backend:

My server file is at /my_backend/src/server.py
My docker file is at /my_backend/Dockerfile.dockerfile

Content of Dockerfile.dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
COPY /src .
WORKDIR /src/app
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
CMD ["python","server.py"]
```

The error message in the command prompt is

```
Attaching to backend, frontend
backend   | python: can't open file 'server.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
backend exited with code 2
```

Feel free to ask for more information.
I used this tutorial: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/dockerizing-angular-application-and-python-backend-bottle-flask-framework-21dcbf8715e5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turn your workdir and copy instructions around to make it work.

```sh
FROM python:3.7-slim
WORKDIR /src/app # workdir first
COPY /src .
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
CMD ["python","server.py"]
```

Answer (score 3):

If your script is in `/src` directory, don't use `WORKDIR /src/app` but `WORKDIR /src` or `CMD ["python","../server.py"]`

Solution 1:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
COPY /src .
WORKDIR /src    # <- HERE
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
CMD ["python","server.py"]
```

Solution 2:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
COPY /src .
WORKDIR /src/app
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
CMD ["python","../server.py"]     # <- HERE, or "/src/server.py"
```

Suggested by @TheFool:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
WORKDIR /src/app  # Swap WORKDIR and COPY
COPY /src .
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
CMD ["python","server.py"]
```

Comment: It will be also nice to state, that `Dockerfile` must not have any extension, and it is nice to put env variables right after from clause and separate dockerfile's logic blocks by blank lines

Comment: I think its still wrong due to the way COPY works. It will copy whats inside src to / and not into /src. WORKDIR should come before COPY to make it work.

Comment: @sudden_appearance, Dockerfile can be named how you wish, as long as you point to it with `-f`

Comment: So, the first solution did not work, I'll try the second one now.

Comment: Read the comment of @TheFool. I believe he's right about WORKDIR

Comment: Yes, the answer of @TheFool worked, thanks everyone